# Invalid program counter value in MIPS

Tags: assembly, recursion, mips

My program does what it's supposed to do recursively, but right after my program calculates my final answer, the program terminates with errors. More specifically: **Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000**

I believe it's a problem with my jr $ra because while debugging my code, I saw that the error is thrown at the second jr $ra right after the program calculates the answer.

How would I solve this problem? I need the program to print out the number stored in register $v0, but the program fails before I can do that.

```
.data
msg: .asciiz "Enter a positive integer n: \n"
msg2: .asciiz "Its CValue is: \n"

.text
li $v0,4
la $a0,msg
syscall
li $v0,5
syscall
move $a0,$v0

cValue:
addi $sp,$sp,-4
sw $ra,0($sp)
bgt $a0,1,recursive
li $v0,1
lw $ra,0($sp)
addi $sp,$sp,4
jr $ra

recursive:
addi $a0,$a0,-1
jal cValue
li $t7,3
mult $v0,$t7
mflo $v0
addi $v0,$v0,1
lw $ra,0($sp)
addi $sp,$sp,4
jr $ra
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last `jr $ra` performed will jump to whatever `$ra` was set to before first entering `cValue`. Since you don't have an initial `jal cValue`, the value of `$ra` will be whatever it was when your program started. Typically that would be somewhere in the C runtime that takes control when your `main` returns, and that's the behavior I get in PcSpim.

I don't know why you get the "Invalid program counter" error since you haven't specified your execution environment. But as I've mentioned above, adding a `jal cValue` should solve the problem by continuing execution after the `jal` once the subroutine has finished. Then you can do whatever you need to do to exit the program cleanly.

Comment: This was the problem. I had to add a jal to my main function after move $a0, $v0. After I did that, I could return to my main function, print my number, and terminate. Thanks!